# How do I loop through days in months in python3?

Tags: python-3.x

Say for the year of 2020, how do I iterate through the days in the months so that my outcome would be in the following format:

Jan1
Jan2
Jan3
....
Jan31
Feb1

I've tried so many things online but I couldnt find an answer. Please help :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far? Can you show us some code snippets?

Comment: the thing is I'm writign a program for somethign bigger and this is a need for the completion, i just figure out a way to get this done

Answer (score 2):

Both of these methods will handle leap years correctly out of the box.

Using a simple `while` loop:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def iter_days(year):
    dt = datetime(year, 1, 1)
    while dt.year == year:
        yield dt
        dt += timedelta(days=1)
```

Using date rules:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, DAILY

def iter_days(year):
    first_date = datetime(year, 1, 1)
    last_date = datetime(year, 12, 31)
    return rrule(DAILY, dtstart=first_date, until=last_date)
```

Both would be used the same:

```py
for dt in iter_days(2020):
    print(dt.strftime('%b%-d'))
```

The format string `'%b%-d'` will give you the format you specified in your question. I don't know if that was a requirement or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is crude but gets what you want for 2020. You'll need to change 366 to 365 for non-leap-years.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import datetime
startDate = '2020-01-01'

start = datetime.datetime.strptime(startDate, '%Y-%m-%d')

for dayNum in range(0,366):
    dayOfYear = start + datetime.timedelta(days=dayNum)
    print(dayOfYear.strftime('%b %d, %Y'))
```

Comment: I think @ibonyun's solution is more elegant than my ugly hack.

Answer (score 0):

The [calendar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html) module offers quite a bit of functionality.

Here is a solution that works for any given year

```
import calendar as cal

for mi in range(1,13):
 _, days = cal.monthrange(2020, mi)
 for d in range(1, days+1):
  print(cal.month_name[mi], d)
```